# Java Rendering Artifacts When Adding Buttons To Semi-Transparent JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jcomponent

I have a problem. I am trying to create "alert" component that I can display in a JFrame. This alert has a semi-transparent background (70% opacity, white) with any trivial amount of JButtons on it. The background itself has rounded corners, and thus I made a custom component.

When rendering this alert, artifacts appear: no alert-background is rendered on the button that is initially selected. When moving my mouse across the buttons, it looks like the text of the buttons is being drawn in two places for no reason.

Screenshots of the artifacts (top = initial render, bottom = moving mouse around):

[image: Initial artifact]

[image: Moving mouse around]

Code that causes these problems:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRoundedTransparentBackground background = new MyRoundedTransparentBackground();
        background.setSize(200, 200);
        background.setLocation(100, 100);

        background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel spacer = new JPanel();
        spacer.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

        GridBagConstraints c = new  GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        background.add(spacer, c);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Hi there");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Bye ...");

        button1.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button1.setFocusPainted(false);
        button1.setBorderPainted(false);

        button2.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button2.setFocusPainted(false);
        button2.setBorderPainted(false);

        c.weighty = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        background.add(button1, c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        background.add(button2, c);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocation(2000, 100);

        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);

        frame.add(background);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyRoundedTransparentBackground extends JComponent {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setColor(new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.7f));
            g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 15, 15);
        }

    }
```

Can someone help me find out what the issue is, and give a potential solution to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: `This alert has a semi-transparent background` - Swing doesn't support semi-transparency. It expects a component to either be opaque or transparent. See: [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information and solutions.

Comment: @camickr Ahh dang... That's a major flaw in Swing then. I'll give that AlphaContainer thing a go. 

Besides Swing, how does JavaFX deal with Transparency and all that, and would you recommend that?

Comment: I haven't used JavaFX, so I can't give any recommendations.